# Calculate the probability with a finite arithmetic progression

Tags: probability, problem-solving, arithmetic-progressions

We have a finite arithmetic progression $ a_n $, where $ n \geq 3 $ and its  $r\neq 0 $.
We draw three different numbers. We have to calculate the probability, that 
these three numbers in the order of drawing will create another arithmetic progression.

My proposition :

$ \Omega={n!\over (n-3)!}$

$ \mathbf{A}= {n \choose 3} \cdot 2$

But I think that my way of thinking about way of counting $ \mathbf{A}$ is incorrect.

Any suggestions how can I count it? Thanks in advice, Kuba!

Comment: Is the progression finite?

Comment: I totally forgot about it :/. Yes, the progression is finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Omega = n(n-1)(n-2)$

We're interested in triples whose elements differ by $r$, $2r$ ... up to $\lceil n/3\rceil r$
Notice, that if a triple $a_i,a_k,a_l$ is OK, then so is $a_l,a_k,a_i$.
My idea was to "stick together" those desired elements that form each triple and calculate their quantity. To be precise: there are $2(n-2)$ triples whose elements differ by r, $2(n-4)$ triples whose elements differ by $2r$ .... and $2(n-2\lceil n/3\rceil)$ triples whose elements differ by $\lceil n/3\rceil r$. Then:
$P(A) = \frac{2(n-2+n-4...+n-2 \lceil n/3\rceil)}{n(n-1)(n-2)}$

Comment: Not exactly  we have different possibilities
For example when the rest of $ {n\ 3} $ is $0$, your idea is good,
-when the rest of $ {n\ 3} $ is $ 1 $ $\mathbf{A}=  2[n-2+n-4...+n-2 \lceil n/3\rceil]+1$,
when the rest of $ {n\ 3} $ is $ 2 $ $\mathbf{A}=  2[n-2+n-4...+n-2 \lceil n/3\rceil]+2$,
so this is completely good answer :)
Cheers

Comment: Let"s check fon $n=7$ for your  $A=16$, but correct answer is $18$, because we have also $a_1,a_4,a_7$ and vice versa, so your answer is incorrect....

Comment: For n=7 according to my answer $A=2[n-2+n-4+n-6]=2*9=18$ and it's all good.

Comment: Please revise your attempt and analyze mine from the beginning. I'd bet it's correct :)

Comment: Hmmmm, but for $n=7$ , the number $ \lceil 7/3\rceil=2$, not 3. In $\lceil n/3\rceil $ we round down, always...

Comment: No. The ceiling function isn't the floor one. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions  <- look at the plot of the "ceiling function" on the right

Comment: $\lceil 0.5\rceil $=1

Comment: I think you just mistook those two together.

Comment: Yeah, now everything is good! Big thanks for you, and shoutout!

Answer (score -1):

Let the sequence be $a_1,a_2,a_3,...a_n$. Then $|\Omega | = {n\choose 3} = {n(n-1)(n-2)\over 6}$

and each good 3-sequence is uniquely defined by it's middle term and the difference $d$. So if middle term is $a_m$ then the difference can be $d,2d,...,(m-1)d$.

So if we have $n=2k$, then we have $$1+2+...+(k-1)+(k-1)+...+2+1 = k(k-1)$$ 
good 3-sequences. So the probability is $$P = {6k(k-1)\over 4k(2k-1)(k-1)} = {3\over 2(n-1)}$$

If $n=2k+1$ then we have $$1+2+...+(k-1)+k+(k-1)+...+2+1 = k(k-1)+k=k^2$$ 
good 3-sequences. So the probability is $$P = {6k^2\over 2(2k+1)k(2k-1)} = {3(n-1)\over 2n(n-2)}$$